# "only actually requires" or "actually only requires"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I want to say:

> XXX actually only requires that YYY to be non-negative.

But I feel weird about this sentence. Should I say:

> XXX only actually requires that....

or

> XXX actually requires only that....

Which one is better?

Comment: More important: remove either *that* or *to*.

Comment: An additional note: the subject ought to read "Does this sentence sound ok?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"actually" really modifies the rest of the statement, so I would write:

> **Actually,** XXX only requires YYY to be non-negative.

Comment: With this phrasing, there is still a bit of ambiguity. It could mean that [XXX only requires YYY] [to be non-negative], or it could mean that [XXX only requires] [YYY to be non-negative]. If the latter is intended, it could be worded as "Actually, XXX only requires **that** YYY be non-negative." If the former, this could be clarified with "Actually, **to be non-negative,** XXX only requires YYY."

Comment: Actually, I don't really like questions with XXX or YYY; I would prefer real words.

Answer (score 1):

Placing 'only' in front of 'actually' would change the meaning, since 'only' would then modify the 'actually' instead of 'requires'.  As to the position of 'only' before or after 'requires', it's virtually indifferent.

Edited after the discussion in comments: ought to have written "since 'only' would then modify the 'actually' instead of 'requires ...'. (better?)

Comment: I want to emphasize "only" part. So I guess I should use "XXX actually only requires that..." right?

Comment: or "XXX actually requires only that..."...

Comment: I'm not sure what it would *mean* to have ***only*** modify ***requires***. That would imply excluding any more extreme actions than "requiring", but I can't imagine what they might be. I'm okay with *This letter only requests a response, it doesn't **require** one*, but I've no idea what possible word could go in *This letter only requires a response, it doesn't **xxx** one*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Your example with an e-mail *only requiring a response* is not the same, methinks, because in the original question there is a clause expanding the 'requires' portion, to which the 'only' really applies.  Imagine your 'email' statement to have such a clause.  It would perhaps stop being awkward, if you build it like this: "This letter only requires a response acknowledging that it was received."

Comment: @Victor: I don't think so. Your counter-example relies on the fact that we're pretty flexible about exactly where ***only*** can be placed in relation to the specific word (or entire phrase, *requires ... was received* in your example) that it modifies. I'm talking about the possibility that in fact ***only*** only modifies the verb ***requires*** (rather than an entire phrase including *what* is required), which is what you mention in your answer.

Comment: Ok, so 'only' does not modify 'requires' but the objective clause that follows.  Then do we consider that placing 'only' *before* 'requires' is incorrect?  "I only want you to be happy" is incorrect then, and ought to be written "I want only you to be happy" or "I want you to only be happy"?  See the difference?

Comment: No. As I said, *we're **pretty flexible** about placement of **only***. Strictly speaking, *I only want you to be happy* is ambiguous (you might continue with *...I don't actually **require** you to be happy*, in which case ***only*** definitely only modifies ***require***). But that's such an unlikely interpretation we'd normally ignore it anyway. If you want to be totally unambiguous about the likely intended sense, you could say *I want only **for** you to be happy* (*for you to be happy* is *all* that I want).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to say is:

1) that XXX has only one requirement,
2) and that the requirement is a condition
3) and the condition is that YYY be non-negative,

and you also want to qualify the above observation with "actually",

then the following would be the most unambiguous way to put it:

"Actually, XXX requires only that YYY be non-negative."

This way you avoid using the to-infinitive, which opens the statement to such interpretations as 1) to be non-negative, XXX only requires YYY; 2) XXX requires YYY only to be non-negative - meaning YYY can be either positive or neutral or in any other state as long as it is not negative.

And putting "only" after the verb eliminates this interpretation: it is only XXX (out of a list of XXX and others) that requires YYY to be non-negative.

Placing "only" just before the subjunctive clause makes it absolutely clear that it modifies the clause.